# Is NSpec dead? is there a successor?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, nspec

Does anyone know if NSpec or similar alternatives are still active?

Been in the Scala world for a little while recently and when I came back to C# I suddenly found the standard unit test style in C# really clunky.

I came across [NSpec](http://nspec.org) and really liked it. Seemed to give me the ability to write tests in the style offered by Typescript and Scala instead of the C# style i'm used to of :

- [Test] When_CharacterAttacksOtherCharacter_OtherCharacterHealthGoesDownByAttackPower
- [Test] When_CharacterAttacksOtherCharacter_OtherCharacterDiesWhenHealthBelow
- [Test] When_CharacterAttacksOtherCharacter_AttackPowerIsMoreWhenTypeAdvantage

it let me write in this style

```
//context methods are discovered by NSpec (any method that contains underscores)
    void describe_BattleSystem()
    {
        //contexts can be nested n-deep and contain befores and specifications
        context["characters are in battle"] = () =>
        {
            before = () =>
            {
                ModifierRepository modifierRepository = new ModifierRepository();
                battleSystem = new BattleSystem(characterAttackPowerRepo, characterHealthRepo, characterTypeRepo, modifierRepository);
            };


            context["character attacks another character"] = () =>
            {
                before = () => battleSystem.Attack("Hero", "Ogre");
                
                it["defending characters' health goes down by attack character attack power"] = () =>
                {
                    battleSystem.GetHealth("Ogre").Should().Be(90);
                };
                
                it["other character dies when health below 0"] = () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
                        battleSystem.Attack("Hero", "Ogre");
                        
                    battleSystem.IsDead("Ogre").Should().Be(true);
                };
            };
        };
    }
```

Which I felt was a much nicer way to write tests.

But it seems NSpec was last updated 4 years ago. And I couldn't get the test runner to work at all. The IDE support seemed **almost** there:

[image: Resharper test runner with NSpec]

But I'm not sure if the .exes are out of date (following the manual steps doesnt work anymore) or if I missed something in the setup and i can't see how its going to unroll to the "It" level. the image above is from ReSharper I also tried it with visual studio with the VS extension and had the same issues.

Does anyone know if NSpec is still alive or if there has been a successor? or anything similar? I'm not really looking for full BDD here (like SpecFlow) What I feel is key is:

- Being able to write tests in string form (get rid of those underscores)
- Nesting tests into sensible units

Or if anyone has a way of doing the above in standard xUnit etc that I'm missing :)

For reference I've uploaded my tests to this git hub folder:
[https://github.com/chrispepper1989/RPGAsAService/tree/nspec_test/RPGAAS/RPGAAS/tests](http://battle%20system%20tests)

It contains the original way I wrote the tests (in standard XUnit) and the NSpec version which I feel I prefer.

Comment: There is MSpec / Machine Specifications: https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications But, no string form, as far as I can tell

Comment: I'm making heavy use of NSpec - not MSpec - in one of my projects and I always just used the Console Runner

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i think id happily use it in a personal project, but not sure if i could justify using it in a client project :(